# Помогите создать проверку для полей формы

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap, form

Помогите создать проверку (required* - если не заполнено не переходит на следующую вкладку)для определенных полей формы (мейл, фото, телефон)
А так же настроить кнопку Отправки чтобы данные отправлялись на почту

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var opacity;
var current = 1;
var steps = $("fieldset").length;

setProgressBar(current);

$(".next").click(function(){

current_fs = $(this).parent();
next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

//Add Class Active
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

//show the next fieldset
next_fs.show();
//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
step: function(now) {
// for making fielset appear animation
opacity = 1 - now;

current_fs.css({
'display': 'none',
'position': 'relative'
});
next_fs.css({'opacity': opacity});
},
duration: 500
});
setProgressBar(++current);
});

$(".previous").click(function(){

current_fs = $(this).parent();
previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

//Remove class active
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

//show the previous fieldset
previous_fs.show();

//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
step: function(now) {
// for making fielset appear animation
opacity = 1 - now;

current_fs.css({
'display': 'none',
'position': 'relative'
});
previous_fs.css({'opacity': opacity});
},
duration: 500
});
setProgressBar(--current);
});

function setProgressBar(curStep){
var percent = parseFloat(100 / steps) * curStep;
percent = percent.toFixed();
$(".progress-bar")
.css("width",percent+"%")
}

$(".submit").click(function(){
return false;
})

});
```

codepen.io/monbrielle/pen/dyYRgPm
Спасибо

Comment: проверку на что? валидацию?

Comment: required* - если не заполнено не переходит на следующую вкладку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
  var opacity;
  var current = 1;
  var steps = $("fieldset").length;

  setProgressBar(current);

  $(".next").click(function(){

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
    
    //check empty required inputs
    if ( !check(current_fs) ) {
      return false;
    }

    //Add Class Active
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show();
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
      step: function(now) {
        // for making fielset appear animation
        opacity = 1 - now;

        current_fs.css({
          'display': 'none',
          'position': 'relative'
        });
        next_fs.css({'opacity': opacity});
      },
      duration: 500
    });
    setProgressBar(++current);
  });

  $(".previous").click(function(){

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //Remove class active
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show();

    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
      step: function(now) {
        // for making fielset appear animation
        opacity = 1 - now;

        current_fs.css({
          'display': 'none',
          'position': 'relative'
        });
        previous_fs.css({'opacity': opacity});
      },
      duration: 500
    });
    setProgressBar(--current);
  });

  function setProgressBar(curStep) {
    var percent = parseFloat(100 / steps) * curStep;
    percent = percent.toFixed();
    $(".progress-bar").css("width",percent+"%");
  }

  $(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
  });
});

function check(block) {
  let inputs = block.find('input[required]'),
      result = true;
  if (inputs?.length) {
    inputs.each(function(i){
      if ( this.value=='' || ( this.type == 'checkbox' && !this.checked) ) {
        result = false;
        if (this.type == 'checkbox') {
          this.style.outline = '1px solid red';
        } else {
          this.style.border = "1px solid red";
        }  
      } else { 
        this.style.border = "none";
        this.style.outline = "none";
      }
    });
  }
  return result;
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

html {
    height: 100%
}

p {
    color: grey
}

#heading {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #673AB7;
    font-weight: normal
}

#msform {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px
}

#msform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative
}

.form-card {
    text-align: left
}

#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none
}

#msform input,
#msform textarea {
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    background-color: #ECEFF1;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 1px
}

#msform input:focus,
#msform textarea:focus {
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: 1px solid #673AB7;
    outline-width: 0
}

#msform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: #673AB7;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 5px;
    float: right
}

#msform .action-button:hover,
#msform .action-button:focus {
    background-color: #311B92
}

#msform .action-button-previous {
    width: 100px;
    background: #616161;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 0px;
    float: right
}

#msform .action-button-previous:hover,
#msform .action-button-previous:focus {
    background-color: #000000
}

.card {
    z-index: 0;
    border: none;
    position: relative
}

.fs-title {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #673AB7;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left
}

.purple-text {
    color: #673AB7;
    font-weight: normal
}

.steps {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: gray;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: right
}

.fieldlabels {
    color: gray;
    text-align: left
}

#progressbar {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: lightgrey
}

#progressbar .active {
    color: #673AB7
}

#progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 400
}

#progressbar #account:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f13e"
}

#progressbar #personal:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f007"
}

#progressbar #payment:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f030"
}

#progressbar #confirm:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f00c"
}

#progressbar li:before {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 45px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: lightgray;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    padding: 2px
}

#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: lightgray;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 25px;
    z-index: -1
}

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
    background: #673AB7
}

.progress {
    height: 20px
}

.progress-bar {
    background-color: #673AB7
}

.fit-image {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-11 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-5 text-center p-0 mt-3 mb-2">
            <div class="card px-0 pt-4 pb-0 mt-3 mb-3">
                <h2 id="heading">Sign Up Your User Account</h2>
                <p>Fill all form field to go to next step</p>
                <form id="msform">
                    <!-- progressbar -->
                    <ul id="progressbar">
                        <li class="active" id="account"><strong>Account</strong></li>
                        <li id="personal"><strong>Personal</strong></li>
                        <li id="payment"><strong>Image</strong></li>
                        <li id="confirm"><strong>Finish</strong></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div> <br> <!-- fieldsets -->
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-card">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-7">
                                    <h2 class="fs-title">Account Information:</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-5">
                                    <h2 class="steps">Step 1 - 4</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div> <label class="fieldlabels">Email: *</label> <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Id" required/> <label class="fieldlabels">Username: *</label> <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="UserName" required/> <label class="fieldlabels">Password: *</label> <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" required/> <label class="fieldlabels">Confirm Password: *</label> <input type="password" name="cpwd" placeholder="Confirm Password" required/><label class="fieldlabels">Checkbox example: *</label> <input type="checkbox" name="chb" required/>
                        </div> <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-card">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-7">
                                    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Information:</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-5">
                                    <h2 class="steps">Step 2 - 4</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div> <label class="fieldlabels">First Name: *</label> <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" /> <label class="fieldlabels">Last Name: *</label> <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" /> <label class="fieldlabels">Contact No.: *</label> <input type="text" name="phno" placeholder="Contact No." /> <label class="fieldlabels">Alternate Contact No.: *</label> <input type="text" name="phno_2" placeholder="Alternate Contact No." />
                        </div> <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" /> <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous" />
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-card">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-7">
                                    <h2 class="fs-title">Image Upload:</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-5">
                                    <h2 class="steps">Step 3 - 4</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div> <label class="fieldlabels">Upload Your Photo:</label> <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*"> <label class="fieldlabels">Upload Signature Photo:</label> <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
                        </div> <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Submit" /> <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous" />
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-card">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-7">
                                    <h2 class="fs-title">Finish:</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-5">
                                    <h2 class="steps">Step 4 - 4</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div> <br><br>
                            <h2 class="purple-text text-center"><strong>SUCCESS !</strong></h2> <br>
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-3"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/GwStPmg.png" class="fit-image"> </div>
                            </div> <br><br>
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-7 text-center">
                                    <h5 class="purple-text text-center">You Have Successfully Signed Up</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

добавил функцию check(), которая берёт все эл-ты с текущего блока (шага) с атрибутом required и проверяет пустые они или нет, если пустые - добавляется красный border и отменяется переход на следующий шаг.

**upd.:** насчет отправки на почту - либо serverside, либо использовать что-то типа [smtp.js](https://smtpjs.com/)

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: подскажите ещё пожалуйста как сделать чтобы чтобы чекбокс "согласится с условиями" так же не пропускал дальше
required не помогает в данном поле

Comment: Добавил в пример

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное за помощь

Comment: помогите пожалуйста ещё столкнулся с выпадающем списком "select" 
как ему сделать такую же проверку?
спасибо большое